# Selecting objects through multiple ManyToMany relationships

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

This seems to be simple question but it is never answered anywhere and there is no obvious answer. I have two "cascading" ManyToMany models:

User has ManyToMany to Tag:

```
class User (models.Model):
  ...
  watches_tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='watched_tag_set', blank=True, null=True)
  ignores_tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='ignored_tag_set', blank=True, null=True)
```

and Tag has ManyToMany to Status:

```
class Tag (models.Model):
  tag = models.TextField ()
  status = models.ManyToManyField (Status)
```

Is there a ORM expression that will give me all the Statuses tagged with tags any given  User watches/ignores? I could iterate over Tags in logic and concatenate QuerySets, but I want to use this in much more complicated Q-expression based query, and I want as much work to be pushed to the database engine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
watched_statuses = Status.objects.filter(tag__watched_tag_set=user)
ignored_statuses = Status.objects.filter(tag__ignored_tag_set=user)
```

(Note that your related names on Tag are confusing since `watched_tag_set` is a set of `Users`, not `Tags`.)